# OpenAM 12 installation on Windows Server 2012 hangs

Tags: openam

During installation of OpenAM 12 running on Apache Tomcat 8, Java 8, Windows Server 2012, it hangs on non-typical for this kind of cases step like "Creating OpenAM suffixImport task".

Could that be permissions issue?

Full log:

```
Checking license acceptance...License terms accepted.
Checking configuration directory C:/OpenAM....Success.
Installing OpenAM configuration store...Success RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding.
Extracting OpenDJ, please wait...Complete
Running OpenDJ setupSetup command: --cli --adminConnectorPort 4444 --baseDN dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org --rootUserDN cn=Directory Manager --ldapPort 50389 --skipPortCheck --rootUserPassword xxxxxxx --jmxPort 1689 --no-prompt --doNotStart --hostname localhost --noPropertiesFile Configuring Directory Server ..... 
...Success.
...Success
Installing OpenAM configuration store in C:/OpenAM/opends...Success.
Creating OpenAM suffixImport task 20160613174244898 scheduled to start immediately
```

Comment: Are you still getting this issue? Are you running tomcat as a Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install using http://localhost in the browser? That can cause issues. OpenAM wants a real FQDN.

Comment: Well, nope. I use FQDN set in hosts file

Comment: I have also seen this issue in Docker containers, when the name returned by 'hostname' can not be resolved by DNS